# SQLAlchemy count of related items equal to filtered items

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

**Tl; Dr:** Need to select SqlAlchemy models, which has the same count of filtered related models, as the full count of related models.

I have a system, where administrator can create "filter groups", each of that can contain multiple "filters". Each "filter" has lots of fields, that are used to compare it against an incoming data. Filters inside a group could be joined by OR or AND operator, and that is specified in filter group.

It is look similar to some email filtering functionality (like in GMail), where you can create filters that are checking against incoming email (like text in subject, body, or 'from' field), end results of that check is combined using 'AND' or 'OR'

My problem is: I don't know how to write final query in SqlAlchemy after all the filters already executed and succesful ones are gathered.

My simplified models:

```py
class FilterGroup(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'filter_groups'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    combine_by: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=False, doc='AND / OR')
    filters: Mapped[List['Filter']] = relationship(
        back_populates='filter_group', lazy='joined', cascade='all, delete'
    )
    ... other useful fields ...

class Filter(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'filters'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    filter_group_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('filter_groups.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    filter_group: Mapped['FilterGroup'] = relationship(back_populates='filters')
    ... lots of fields to filter on ...
```

I'm creating complex sqlalchemy query, what in result looks like:

```py
filters_query = sqlalchemy.select(
   Filter.id, Filter.filter_group_id
).where(*where_filters) # where_filters is a list with lots of filtering rules
```

So, this query returns all the successfully matched filters, and now I want to select FilterGroups what corresponding to that filters. When `combine_by` is set to `OR` - I need just one filter matched to take it's group, so I'm usign EXISTS. But when `combine_by` is `AND` - I need to have the same number of selected filters as there are related to the Group (so, all the filters should be matched)

What I have:

```
filter_groups_query = sqlalchemy.select(FilterGroup).where(
    or_(
        # This works!
        and_(
            FilterGroup.combine_by == 'OR',
            exists().where(
                FilterGroup.id == filters_query.subquery().c.filter_group_id,
            ),
        ),
        # And this does not work :(
        and_(
            FilterGroup.combine_by == 'AND',
            sqlalchemy.select(func.count()).filter(Filter.filter_group_id == FilterGroup.id)
            == sqlalchemy.select(func.count()).filter(
                filter_query.subquery().c.filter_group_id == FilterGroup.id
            ),
        ),
    )
)
```

Second block got converted into "False" in SQL :(

That is my last try, but I've tried a lot of different variants, what didn't work.

I know how to write this in PostgreSQL, and that's quite easy:

```sql
WITH filters_query as (
    select id, filter_groups_id from (...filter_query...)
)
SELECT * from filter_groups WHERE
(
    filter_groups.combine_by = 'OR'
    AND
    exists (select 1 from filters_query where filter_group_id = filter_groups.id)
) 
OR 
(
    filter_groups.combine_by = 'AND'
    AND
    (select count(*) from filters where filter_group_id = filter_groups.id) 
    = 
    (select count(*) from filters_query where filter_group_id = filter_groups.id)
)
```

But I need to create sqlalchemy query, not the raw request, so I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, answering my own question.

Short description with lots of comments in code:

1. query, counting filters by each group should be created based on filters_query:

```py
# Query to count number of Filters grouped by filter_group_id
filters_query_count = (
    # Starting query with "select count(1)"
    Query(func.count(1))
    # Adding "where filter_group.id = filter_group_id" (Correlated)
    .filter(FilterGroup.id == filters_query.subquery().c.filter_group_id)
    # Adding "group by filter_group.id"
    .group_by(FilterGroup.id)
    # Adding "as found_filters_count"
    .label('found_filters_count')
)
```

So, that query is automatically became correlated when added to any FilterGroup query, because where are FilterGroup model in filter condition.

2. This query should be compared with count of filters related to a FilterGroup:

```py
# Queriyng FilterGroup objects
filter_groups_query = sqlalchemy.select(FilterGroup).where(
    # One of the following conditions met
    or_(
        # First variant, for "OR" condition:
        and_(
            # If FilterGroup.combine_by is OR
            FilterGroup.combine_by == 'OR',
            # and there are exists at least one record in "filters_query"
            # which have the save filter_group_id as id of selecting FilterGroup
            exists().where(
                FilterGroup.id == filters_query.subquery().c.filter_group_id,
            ),
        ),
        # Second variant, for "AND" condition
        and_(
            # If combine_by is "AND"
            FilterGroup.combine_by == 'AND',
            # If count of records in filters_query, grouped by FilterGroup
            # equal to count of Filters that has filter_group_id == id of FilterGroup
            # it means that all of the existing filters in that FilterGroup
            # are matched to condition, and FilterGroup should be selected 
            filters_query_count
            == sqlalchemy.select(func.count())
            .filter(Filter.filter_group_id == FilterGroup.id)
            .scalar_subquery(),
        ),
    )
)
```

So, this request build working SQL, and even it doesn't look like my own idea on how it should be in SQL, it working good.